# preg_match for multiple words

Tags: php, regex, string-matching, cpu-word, word-boundaries

I want to test a string to see it contains certain words.

i.e:

```
$string = "The rain in spain is certain as the dry on the plain is over and it is not clear";
preg_match('`\brain\b`',$string);
```

But that method only matches one word. How do I check for multiple words?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Something like:

```
preg_match_all('#\b(rain|dry|clear)\b#', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: @Autolycus I was going to add a space `\s` around the words, but then I noticed you already used a word boundary `\b`.

Comment: @Autolycus The `#` at the beginning and end mark the beginning and end of the regex and are necessary (that or any other character) so that you can add switches at the end, like `#i` for case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_match('~\b(rain|dry|certain|clear)\b~i',$string);
```

You can use the pipe character (`|`) as an "or" in a regex.

If you just need to know if any of the words is present, use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) as above. If you need to match all the occurences of any of the words, use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('~\b(rain|dry|certain|clear)\b~i', $string, $matches);
```

Then check the `$matches` variable.

Comment: That 'i' for ignore case helped!

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

> "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster."

Comment: `strpos()` and `strstr()` do not offer word boundaries.  This answer shows why the asker's approach fails, but it does not offer a resolving technique.  This answer should have been a comment under the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('\brain\b',$string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Missing delimiters, and doesn't return more than one value