# PHP preg_match getting string between 2 chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Please consider this string:

```
$string = 'hello world /foo bar/';
```

The end result I wish to obtain:

```
$result1 = 'hello world';
$result2 = 'foo bar';
```

What I've tried:

```
preg_match('/\/(.*?)\//', $string, $match);
```

Trouble is this only return "foo bar" and not "hello world". I can probably strip "/foo bar/" from the original string, but in my real use case that would take additional 2 steps.

Comment: What's wrong with `explode("/", $string);` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match for multiple words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689521/preg-match-for-multiple-words)

Comment: @Tuesdave that thread doesn't answer my question

Comment: Are you looking for how to do this with a regex or just how to do it. For why the regex doesn't work see, https://regex101.com/r/pZ4bL2/1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression only matches what you tell it to match. So you need to have it match everything including the `/`s and then group the `/`s.

This should do it:

```
$string = 'hello world /foo bar/';
preg_match('~(.+?)\h*/(.*?)/~', $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/507636
Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oL5sX9/1 (delimiters escaped, in PHP usage changed the delimiter)

The `0` index is everything found, `1` the first group, `2` the second group. So between the `/`s is `$match[2]`; the `hello world` is `$match[1]`. The `\h` is any horizontal whitespace before the `/` if you want that in the first group remove the `\h*`. The `.` will account for whitespace (excluding new line unless specified with `s` modifier).

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = explode("/", $string);
```

results in

```
$result[0] == 'hello world ';
$result[1] == 'foo bar';
```

You might want to replace the space in hello world. More info here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Comment: This will result in:

$result[1] == 'foo bar/';

Also it's not applicable to my real use case.

Comment: huh, pretty sure it will be $result[1] == 'foo bar' and $result[2] will be an empty string, since all / are replaced

Comment: Ok in any case, explode is not applicable in my real use case because the number of array items matter and it's not constant.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this conversion issue, use below code.

```
$string      = 'hello world /foo bar/';
$returnValue =  str_replace(' /', '/', $string);
$result      =  explode("/", $returnValue);
```

If you want to print it, put below lines in your code.

```
echo $pieces[0]; // hello world
echo $pieces[1]; // foo bar
```

https://eval.in/507650